# How I can scaling itemscontrol items proportionally without trimming and without scrollbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application, the main container is a 3x3 grid. On the left (column=0, row=0, ColumnSpan=2) is the ItemsControl. It should display the names of the axes and their coordinates. The number of elements in the range of 1-9. They should be placed in the item control completely. The second day I can not find a suitable solution. could you help me?

Now the right side (Textblock) is smaller than the left. How to make both textblocks have approximately the same size?

**Xaml**

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Axes}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Height>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{local:HeightConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}"
                                         Path="ItemsSource.Count" Mode="OneWay" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Grid.Height>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0">
                            <TextBlock 
                                       Text="{Binding AxisName}"
                                       FontSize="40"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1"
                                 Grid.Row="0">
                            <TextBlock 
                                       Text="{Binding AxisPosition}"
                                       FontSize="40"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

**DataContext class:**

```
class Data
    {
        public Data()
        {

        }
        private readonly ObservableCollection<Axis> _axes = new ObservableCollection<Axis> { new Axis{ AxisName = "X:", AxisPosition = 12345.678 },
        new Axis { AxisName = "Y:", AxisPosition = 12345.678 }, new Axis { AxisName = "Z:", AxisPosition = 12345.678 } };
        public ObservableCollection<Axis> Axes => _axes;
    }

    class Axis
    {
        public string AxisName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double AxisPosition
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class HeightConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(values[0] is double actHeight && values[1] is int count)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                    throw new DivideByZeroException();
                return actHeight / count;
            }
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You simple need to add 'Width' parameter

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: ColumnDefinition  has * value by default.